# Visualising big set of points with third feature as a color - a way to improve a speed

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a pretty big dataset (around `5e5` rows) of `(x, y)` coordinates with additional feature `z`. It's something like this:

```
x <- rnorm(1e6, 0, 5)
y <- rnorm(1e6, 0, 10)
dist <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
z <- exp(-(dist / 8)^2)
```

I want to plot them with a `z` feature used as a color aesthetic. But simple `geom_point` takes a while with such a big dataset:

```
data.frame(x, y, z) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x, y, color = z))
```

[image]

So I think I need a way to aggregate points in some way. One approach would be to divide a plane to some small squares and average all the `z` values for points that lie in a square. But it can be a little cumbersome in the long term and it's probably better to use some of already available tools. So I thought about `geom_hex` as a geom that would look good in my case. But `fill` aesthetic is setup to `count` as default. So my questions are:

- Can default `fill` value of `geom_hex` be easily changed to an average of `z` feature?
- If not, how can I create hexagons instead of squares, so that `z` value can be averaged within hexagons and then plotted?
- Is there any other way to improve a speed of plotting such a dataset?

## Edit:

Comparison of proposed solutions:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  'stat_summary_hex' = {data.frame(x, y, z) %>%                                                                                                   
    ggplot( aes(x, y, z=z )) + stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) mean(x))},
  'round_and_group' = {data.frame(x, y, z) %>%                                                   
      mutate(x=round(x, 0), y=round(y, 0)) %>%                                  
      group_by(x,y) %>%                                                         
      summarize(z = mean(z)) %>%                                                
      ggplot() + geom_hex(aes(x, y, fill = z), stat="identity")}
)

Unit: milliseconds
             expr        min        lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
 stat_summary_hex   2.243791   2.38539   2.454039   2.426123   2.50871   2.963176   100
  round_and_group 183.785828 186.38851 188.296828 187.347476 189.10874 218.668487   100
```

Comment: For draft work, plotting, say, only 10% of all observations (sampled randomly each time, just to average out any weird patterns) could be a solution!

Comment: Regarding your first 2 questions: an awful lot of stuff can actually be accessed if you just query the plot object (including data meant for plotting). Presumably, recalculating the z values when moving from squares to hexagons could be viewed a subsetting problem.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that plotting a sample of data is not an option for me.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059

Comment: If you use my rounding approach, you don't need `geom_hex`. You can use `geom_point`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it could help `stat_summary_hex()`, or `stat_summary_2d()`.

They are similar to `stat_summary()`, the data are divided in bins with `x` and `y`, then summarised by `z`, using the function specified in `stat_summary_hex()` (or `stat_summary_2d()`).

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x, y, z) %>%  
# here you can specify the function that welcomes the z parameter                                                                                              
ggplot( aes(x, y, z=z )) + stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) mean(x))
```

[image]

It is going to answer the your second question (hex), and your third question (seems ok with perfomance as you stated), in place of using  `geom_hex()` (so it seems there is a trade of between `geom_hex()` and velocity).

**EDIT**

Looking at your questions, I've microbenchmarked the function with different values:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 3.5e5 205.0363 214.6925 236.8149 225.2286 238.6536  494.7897   100
   1e6 575.4861 597.4161 665.4396 620.9151 702.1622 1143.7011   100
```

Also, you can also specify the bins, to have more or less "precise" hexes. The default value should be 30, that means it's going to plot the points in an area of 30 * 30 hexes:

```
data.frame(x, y, z) %>%                                                                                            
ggplot( aes(x, y, z=z )) + stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) mean(x), bins = 60)
```

As example ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387376/r-error-could-not-find-function-multiplot-using-cookbook-example) the `multiplot()` function, if necessary):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 5)                                                     
y <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 10)                                                    
dist <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)                                                   
z <- exp(-(dist / 8)^2) 

library(tidyverse)

a1 <- data.frame(x, y, z) %>% 
      ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x, y, color = z)) 

b1 <- data.frame(x, y, z) %>%  
     ggplot( aes(x, y, z=z )) + stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) mean(x))

c1 <- data.frame(x, y, z) %>%  
      ggplot( aes(x, y, z=z )) + stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) mean(x), bins = 60)

multiplot(a1,b1,c1, cols = 3)
```

[image]

As you can see, the more you add hexes, the most you are closer to your original points.

---

With data:

```
x <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 5)                                                     
y <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 10)                                                    
dist <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)                                                   
z <- exp(-(dist / 8)^2)
```

Comment: This is a nice approach! However, I have two questions. 1. When plotting a data of `1e6` generated as an example it works really fast, but when plotting my original data (with `3.5e5`, so significantly less) it takes about 2 minutes to create a plot. Do you have any idea why? 2. On the `geom_hex` plotted this way you can observe some blank gaps, which make the plot contaminated - what causes them and how can I remove them?

Comment: Thanks! I've answered to your question in the edit. The beahviour or different datasets is fine using `microbench`, so maybe try to restart R. Maybe the blanks are there because maybe you are not using `set.seed()` so pseudo-random functions like `rnorm()` are not giving the same data, or  maybe you need to specify the `bins` as in the edit.

Answer (score 5):

`stat="identity"` is used on bar/column charts to use value instead of count. This appears to work with geom_hex

```r
library(dplyr)                                                            
library(ggplot2)                                                          
x <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 5)                                                     
y <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 10)                                                    
dist <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)                                                   
z <- exp(-(dist / 8)^2)                                                   

##  Summarize to rounded x and y, calculate mean(z), use stat = "identity"
data.frame(x, y, z) %>%                                                   
mutate(x=round(x, 0), y=round(y, 0)) %>%                                  
group_by(x,y) %>%                                                         
summarize(z = mean(z)) %>%                                                
ggplot() + geom_hex(aes(x, y, fill = z), stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using rasters for this:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

p = data.frame(x, y, z)
coordinates(p) = ~x+y

r = raster(nrows=500, ncols=500, ext = extent(c(range(c(x,y)), range(c(x,y)))), crs=CRS("+init=epsg:28992"))
r = rasterize(p, r, 'z', fun=mean)
levelplot(r)
```

[image]

NB If you don't want to use RasterVis you can plot with ggplot or base graphics if you prefer. E.g. with ggplot, we can do

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE) ) +
  geom_raster(aes(x, y, fill = layer)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When datasets sizes get large, it can be worth to switch to a specialized software. For example, [datashader](http://www.datashader.org) can draw colored scatter plots of large datasets in a reasonable amount of time. However, it currently has no R interface (only Python).