# ploting mutlple graphs on the same plot with models output

Tags: r

I am R novice but need to it for my data analysis.

I want to plot multiple line charts from different locations (under the same study) on the same plot. My data frames are results of non-linear random effects models.

## Below is the model output and plot. Now I have four different locations (1 to 4) and I need to plot on the same graph for comparison.

`{r}
Location1.model<- glmer(Completeness ~ Weeks + I(Weeks*Weeks) + (1|street), data = location.1, family = binomial())
summary(D1.model)
Weeks_Num <- 1:165
Time.effect <- fixef(D1.model)[1] + fixef(D1.model)[2]*Weeks_Num + fixef(D1.model)[3]*Weeks_Num*Weeks_Num
Time.probs <- inv.logit(Time.effect)
plot(Time.probs~Weeks_Num, pch=".", col="blue", type="l", xlim=c(0,175), ylim=c(0,1))`

[plo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL05l.png)
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R error "could not find function 'multiplot' " using Cookbook example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387376/r-error-could-not-find-function-multiplot-using-cookbook-example)

Answer (score 0):

multiplot or grid.arrange would do the trick. Here is a thread were their use is discussed.

[R error "could not find function 'multiplot' " using Cookbook example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387376/r-error-could-not-find-function-multiplot-using-cookbook-example)

This is a repeated topic, in the future try to search this site for a similar thread- many already exist for multipane plotting.